# Mapping a JSON object to part of a view model using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm having trouble building a view model that is composed of some data from the server and some added manually.

I keep getting that m() is undefined from the code below:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMLMr/)

```
function getServerData()
{
     var m = 
         {
             FlowID:5,
             Amount:120
         };
    return m;
}

var entity = getServerData();

var vm = 
{
    m: ko.mapping.fromJS(entity),
    x: ko.observable("additional prop")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I'm trying to bind it as follows:

```
<input data-bind="value: x()" />
<input data-bind="value: m().FlowID" />
<input data-bind="value: m().Amount" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping plugin does not turn your object into an observable only its properties.

So after the `ko.mapping.fromJS(entity)` call `m` won't be a `ko.observable`.

So you just need to write:

```
<input data-bind="value: m.FlowID" />
<input data-bind="value: m.Amount" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhYFL/).

If you want to make your original binding work, then you need to change your `vm`:

```
var vm = 
{
    m: ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(entity)),
    x: ko.observable("additional prop")
};
```